# How to allow attachment to be displayed in a iframe

Tags: html, attachments, iframe

I want to display an attachment in a iframe,
I tried adding `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat:"server"/>` in the Master Page but it didn't work, do you have any suggestions about how to approach the problem.

Comment: Where do you want to see the attachment?

Comment: The attachment is a pdf and i want to display it in a section of another webpage (not SharePoint) for the pdf reader, I'm using an opensource js that render the file in a iframe